How to create pickup Distance Calculation miles pricing in WordPress
I am trying to pick up Distance Calculation miles pricing in WordPress but I have not succeeded yet. any help would be appreciated.
Here is my code. but I don't know what is wrong with my code.
HTML Form
in WordPress where users can input the pickup and destination locations.
function google_maps_distance_calculator_shortcode() {
    ob_start();
    ?>
    <div class="distance-calculator-form">
        <form id="distance-calculator-form">
            <h2>Calculate Distance and Cost</h2>

            <label for="pickup">Pickup Location:</label>
            <input type="text" id="pickup" name="pickup" placeholder="Enter pickup location"><br>

            <label for="destination">Destination Location:</label>
            <input type="text" id="destination" name="destination" placeholder="Enter destination location"><br>

            <p>Distance: <span id="distance">0 km</span></p>
            <p>Total Cost: <span id="total-cost">$0.00</span></p>

            <!-- Button to calculate distance and cost -->
            <button type="button" id="calculate-button">Calculate Distance & Cost</button>
        </form>
    </div>
    <?php
    return ob_get_clean();
}
add_shortcode('google_maps_distance_calculator', 'google_maps_distance_calculator_shortcode');


JavaScript to Calculate Distance Using Google Maps API
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    let map;
    let directionsService;
    let directionsRenderer;

    function initMap() {
        // Initialize the Google Maps objects
        directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
        directionsRenderer = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
            center: { lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644 },
            zoom: 8
        });
        directionsRenderer.setMap(map);
    }

    function calculateDistance() {
        const pickup = document.getElementById('pickup').value;
        const destination = document.getElementById('destination').value;

        if (pickup && destination) {
            const request = {
                origin: pickup,
                destination: destination,
                travelMode: 'DRIVING'
            };

            directionsService.route(request, function(result, status) {
                if (status == 'OK') {
                    directionsRenderer.setDirections(result);

                    const distance = result.routes[0].legs[0].distance.value / 1000; // distance in km
                    const cost = distance * 2; // Example: $2 per km

                    document.getElementById('distance').textContent = distance.toFixed(2) + ' km';
                    document.getElementById('total-cost').textContent = '$' + cost.toFixed(2);
                } else {
                    alert('Could not calculate distance: ' + status);
                }
            });
        } else {
            alert('Please enter both pickup and destination locations.');
        }
    }

    document.getElementById('calculate-button').addEventListener('click', calculateDistance);

    // Load the map
    initMap();
});


Add Google Maps Script to Your WordPress Site
function enqueue_google_maps_script() {
    wp_enqueue_script('google-maps', 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_GOOGLE_MAPS_API_KEY&libraries=places', null, null, true);
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'enqueue_google_maps_script');


Add Styling
.distance-calculator-form {
    max-width: 600px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 20px;
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    border-radius: 8px;
}

.distance-calculator-form label {
    display: block;
    margin-bottom: 8px;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.distance-calculator-form input[type="text"] {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 8px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-radius: 4px;
}

#calculate-button {
    background-color: #007cba;
    color: white;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 4px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

#calculate-button:hover {
    background-color: #005f8d;
}

#distance, #total-cost {
    font-weight: bold;
}



I have tested it and its working. Do you get any errors in your console?

if you want Miles and not Km you just need to convert meters in miles whit something like this: const distance = result.routes[0].legs[0].distance.value * 0.000621371192; //meters to miles

Welcome! I am trying to pick up Distance Calculation miles pricing in WordPress but I have not succeeded yet. - this doesn't really help. We need to have an idea of what your console says, or any errors that WP is generating.
